# Using variables in Django URLs?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Is it possible to use URLs like this Django -

```
url(r'^movie/(?P<id1>\d+)/forum/(?P<id2>\d+)/$', "movies.views.show_comments", name='comments'),
```

This is my view -

```
def show_comments(request, id1, id2):
```

This is the template -

```
<a href="{% url 'comments' object.pk f.pk %}"><h4>{{ f.topic }}</h4></a>
```

But when i go to the url, it doesn't call the view function, it just reloads to the same page. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the rest of your urls.py?

Comment: I looked into the other URLs and found the mistake, thanx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My other URL-

```
url(r'^movie/(?P<id>\d+)', "movies.views.show_detail", name='detail'),
```

was incomplete, i had to put /$ after it. So it should be like this-

```
url(r'^movie/(?P<id>\d+)/$', "movies.views.show_detail", name='detail'),
```